# Attach and detach a Rectangle to a moving Rectangle in QML

Tags: qt, animation, qml, qtquick2

I want to implement in [qml](/questions/tagged/qml) that as long as I hold down a button, the two rectangles move together, but as soon as I release it, one of the rectangles stays where it was at the moment of release.

Let the moving `Rectangle` be the master and its code be as follows:

```js
Rectangle {
    id: master
    x: 10
    y: 10
    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: "#00ff00"

    Behavior on x {
        NumberAnimation {
            duration: 2000
        }
    }
}
```

The code of the slave that should move with the master as long as the button is held down is as follows:

```js
Rectangle {
    id: slave
    x: 100
    y: 100
    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: "#ff0000"
}
```

Currently I've made the following attempt to attach and detach the slave to the master:

```js
ToggleButton {
    id: attach
    x: 300
    y: 300
    text: qsTr("Attach")

    onClicked: {
        if (checked) {
            slave.parent = master
        } else {
            slave.parent = mainWindow
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the master is already moving, pressing the button will jump the slave to the position it would have been if it had moved with the master from the beginning, then continues to move with the master even after the button is released.

How can I arbitrarily attach other objects to moving objects and then detach them in [qml](/questions/tagged/qml)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of attaching the slave as a child of master is what is causing the jump. As soon as the slave is reparented, its x and y of 100 place it there in relation to its new parent `master`, not where it was in relation to mainWindow.

When you reparent it, you need to set slave's x and y relative to master to be the translation of the x and y from the mainWindow's coordinate system into master's coordinate system. Look at `Item::mapFromItem` and `Item::mapToItem` to see how to translate the slave's x and y of 100 in the context of `mainWindow` to the same physical position on the screen but in terms of the new parent `master`.

Note, you will need to do the same thing in reverse when you stop the drag and reparent the slave back to the mainWindow.

Here's a shot at some code updates:

```
ToggleButton {
    id: attach
    x: 300
    y: 300
    text: qsTr("Attach")

    onClicked: {
        if (checked) {
            var newPoint = mainWindow.contentItem.mapToItem(master, slave.x, slave.y);
            slave.parent = master;
            slave.x = newPoint.x;
            slave.y = newPoint.y;
        } else {
            var newPoint = master.mapToItem(mainWindow.contentItem, slave.x, slave.y);
            slave.parent = mainWindow.contentItem;
            slave.x = newPoint.x;
            slave.y = newPoint.y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works absolutely fine. Thanks! In the meantime, I also realized why the `slave` continued to move with the `master` after releasing the button. If `mainWindow` is a `Window`, its `contentItem` should be used when reparenting the `slave`, i.e. `slave.parent = mainWindow.contentItem`.